# Does twig autoquote attributes?

Tags: twig

I've found it weird to notice that assembling `data-attribute`s as string and placing it on html node results in attribute value double quoted.

If i leave it unquoted:

```
{% set dataId = '' %}
{% if id is defined %}
    {% set dataId = ' ' ~ 'data-id=' ~ id %}
{% endif %}
```

and put on html node:

```
<div class="testDiv"{{ dataId }}>
```

then the `data-attribute` is correctly quoted.

Is this reliable behavior of twig? Why does it work that way?

Comment: No, this is not something `twig` does. The output you are seeing is the cleaned source created by your browser. Verify that this is not normal behavior [here](https://twigfiddle.com/lylncu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the browser was fixing quotes for me. To be able to output parameters properly, one haz to:

Include quotes in the string:

```
{% set dataId = ' ' ~ 'data-id="' ~ id ~ '"' %}
```

**And** use `raw` filter to prevent escaping quote characters:

```
<div class="testDiv"{{ dataId | raw }}>
```